# AWS Cognito OIDC Identity Provider Setup Error: Unable to contact well-known endpoint

Tags: amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I am attempting to add an OIDC Identity Provider to my AWS Cognito User Pool, but I encounter an error:

[InvalidParameterException] Failed to create identity provider
code: InvalidParameterException
message: Unable to contact well-known endpoint.

I'm looking to understand the error's root cause and how to resolve it. Can anyone help?

I've tried to follow this guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-oidc-idp.html

Comment: Hi Ricardo, welcome. What provider and what information did you provide? The well known URL should be in the docs of the identity provider; this won't be AWS related.